# UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate cut delegates not called

Tags: ios, swift, airprint

I am able to print via AirPrint through the `UIPrintInteractionController`.

All the delegate calls get called but two:

```
func printInteractionController(_ printInteractionController: UIPrintInteractionController, cutLengthFor paper: UIPrintPaper) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func printInteractionController(_ printInteractionController: UIPrintInteractionController, chooseCutterBehavior availableBehaviors: [Any]) -> UIPrinterCutterBehavior {
    return UIPrinterCutterBehavior.noCut
}
```

I am trying to figure out why these two calls never get called. How can I cause the `cut` related two calls shown above to get called?

Comment: Is it a roll-cut printer?

Comment: yes. It is an AirPrint enabled receipt printer.

Comment: Hmmm, so this sounds like a bug (not your bug)... I'd suggest filing a bug report at Apple's site, with details

Comment: that's what I thought. but, wasn't sure. I'll do that.

Comment: The printer manufacturer admitted their driver does not support AirPrint 100%, so those calls are not called because of the printer driver, not because of Apple. Looks like Apple is in the clear, which also makes sense with the Apple docs where they say "it may be called". That is because the printer might not support AirPrint 100%. Too bad.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I suggest you answer your own question and (after 48 hours) accept your own answer to close out this question. It may be useful to others!